# How find this minimum of the value $f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(100)$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, elementary-set-theory, inequality

Give the positive integer set $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,100\}$, and define function
$f:A\to A$ and

(1):such for any $1\le i\le 99$,have
$$|f(i)-f(i+1)|\le 1$$
(2): for any $1\le i\le 100$,have $$f(f(i))=100$$

find the minium of the value
$$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)+\cdots+f(99)+f(100)$$

maye this is nice problem,and I want use $|f(i)-f(i+1)|\le 1$,But I can't it.Thank you

Now it is said this answer is 8350

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the largest number such that $f(n)\ne 100$.  By property (2), there does not exist an $i$ such that $f(i)=n$; by property (1), the graph of $f$ cannot "cross" $n$.  Thus $f$ has these two properties:

(i) $f(A)\subseteq[n+1,100]$

(ii) $f([n+1,100]) = \{100\}$

Furthermore, any function having properties (i) and (ii) has property (2).

Of all functions satisfying properties (1), (i), and (ii), the smallest (pointwise, and therefore also in the sense of $\sum_i f(i)$) will have a graph that looks either like

```
100             * * * * *
              *
            *
          *
        *
      *
    *




    1 2 3 ... n n+1 ... 100
```

or like

```
100                   * * * * * *
                    *
                  *
                *
              *
n+1 * * * * *



    1 2 3    ...    n n+1 ... 100
```

For functions of these types, the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{100} f(i)$ can be computed explicitly as a function of $n$; it'll turn out to be piecewise quadratic in $n$, so you can find the minimum using standard techniques from high school algebra.

Comment: Wouldn't be also depend on the number $k$ where $k$ is such that $f(i)=n+1$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ ?

Comment: That value is forced by taking the minimum possible values for the function; going right-to-left on the graph, you want to go down as fast as possible, so you start going down at $n$, going down 1 unit for every 1 unit you move to the left.  (I'm speaking quite informally here, of course; a formal realization of this part of the argument would look a lot like the start of the answer by @NS )

Comment: Let me put it another way.  To minimize the values of the function, obviously you want $k$ as large as possible, and what "possible" means here is that you have to leave enough time to get back up to 100 by the time $i=n+1$, subject to the speed constraint from property (1).

Comment: Can you include the part of finding the minimum? So there is a complete solution posted.

Comment: This does not feel like a proof. Why can't the function consist of 2 steps?

Comment: @CalvinLin A two-step function would not be as small as possible given the constraints (1),(i),(ii).  A minimal function, subject to these constraints, drops diagonally down-left from $(n+1,100)$; the two cases arise depending on whether such movement hits $x=0$ first or hits $y=n+1$ first, which depends on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As Test Observed, here is a start, the solution is incomplete.

First observe that by repeatedly applying  $(1)$ you get the following:

If $1 \leq i < j < 100$ then

$$\left|f(i)-f(j)\right| \leq j-i \,.$$

Now, if $f(i)=j$ we either have $j =100$ or, by the above

$$ 100-j =|f(i)-f(j) | \leq |j-i| \,.$$

This implies that

$$100-j \leq i-j \, \mbox{or} \, 100-j \leq j-i \,.$$

Therefore , for all $1 \leq i \leq 99$ we have

$$ f(i) \geq \frac{100+i}{2}$$

As $f(i)$ is an integer, for all $1 \leq i\leq 99$ we have

$$f(i) \geq [ \frac{100+i}{2} ] \,,$$
where $[]$ denotes rounded up.

Next, let $f(1)=a$ with $51 \leq a \leq 100$.

I would cover the case $f(1)=100$ separately, lets look at the case $51 \leq a \leq 99$.

The solution can be completed in a very ugly way, by covering all the cases for $f(1)$, but there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: $f(50)=75$, $f(f(50))=f(75)=88$. If I am correct you don't have $f(f(i))=100$.
I don't see if you used hypothesis (2) at all.

Comment: @test123 UPS,,,

Comment: hello,so can find this minimum of is ?

Answer (score 1):

Claim: to achieve the minimum, f(n) is a non decreasing function. Suppose not, take the natural construction $f^*(n)$ where we smooth out the decreasing part, show that it satisfies the conditions and has a smaller sum.

Claim: Suppose that The image of $f(n)$ consists of $k$ elements. Then, because we have a non decreasing function, we see that the minimum sum occurs when we have $f(1)=\ldots=f(100-2k+2)=100-k+1, f(100-2k +j)=100-k+j-1$ for j from 3 to k and $f(100-k+1)=\ldots=f(100)=100$.

It remains to verify that the minimum sum is achieved at $k=34$  This is easily done n

Answer (score 0):

**(Edited)**

My try:

$$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
67,& \mbox{if } 1\le x\le 34;\\
33+x,& \mbox{if } 34\le x \le 67;\\
100, &\mbox{if } 67\le x \le 100.\end{array} \right.
$$

Then $$f(1)+f(2)+...+f(100)=34\cdot 67 + (68+69+...+99) + 34\cdot 100 =2278 + 2672 + 3400 = \large{8350}.$$

---

My approach:

Denote $A_{100}$ is the set of $a\in A$, that $f(a)=100$.

If $A_{100}=A$, it isn't optimal solution ($f(x)\equiv 100$).

Then $A_{100}$ is "bounded" with the set $A_{99}$ (set of such $a\in A$, that $f(a)=99$).
Then (2) $\implies f(99)=100$.

But if $A_{99} \bigcup A_{100} = A$, then it isn't optimal solution too.

Next step: then $A_{99}$ is "bounded" with the set $A_{98}$ (set of such $a$ ...). Then (2) $\implies f(98)=100$.

And so on...

Comment: Why is this the minimum?

Comment: @Oleg567 You need $f(100)=99$ since $f(50)=100$ and $f(f(50))=100$.

Comment: @N.S. I'm not sure by 100%, but I added my approach now.

Comment: @Test123, thanks, corrected.

Comment: @Oleg567 I can't understand how your approach shows that the total you found is the minimum.

Comment: @Test123, using this approach, I build typical classes of functions (trying to make last non-zero set $A_n$ as large as possible), and choose best of them.